# How to install RSWebParts.cab on SQL Server 2014 and Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-2016

I am trying to install RSWebParts.cab to use Report Viewer on SharePoint 2016 but I got error like this:

```
Install-SPWebPartPack : Failed to extract the cab file in the solution.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-SPWebPartPack -LiteralPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...tallWebPartPack:SPCmdletInstallWebPartPack) [Install-SPW
   ebPartPack], SPException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletInstallWebPartPack
```

The path that i used to install:

```
Install-SPWebPartPack -LiteralPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Reporting Services\SharePoint\RSWebParts.cab" -GlobalInstall
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per below link: SSRS 2014 is not supported in SP2016.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/supported-combinations-of-sharepoint-and-reporting-services-server